# Visual Studio Build Tools fails to recognize "net5.0-windows"

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

Is it possible to build a .NET 5 project with the Visual Studio Build Tools? Or is my installation not working?

Note: I can't use the dotnet.exe, since i have to build with the WiX-Toolset.

Installed:

- Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde für .NET Framework
- .NET SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
  Version:   5.0.100
  Commit:    5044b93829

msbuild.exe used from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Error:

```
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(93,5): error NETSDK1013: Der TargetFramework-Wert "net5.0-windows" wurde nicht erkann
t. Unter Umständen ist die Schreibweise nicht korrekt. Andernfalls müssen die Eigenschaften TargetFrameworkIdentifier und/oder TargetFrameworkVersion explizit angegeben werden. [C:\GitLab-Runner\builds
\mq82bps2\0\capps\developer\mfinder\MFinder\MFinder.csproj]
```

Also the msbuild.exe searches in the path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\` and not `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\`. Any hints on that?

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

Comment: 16.7 does not support .NET 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Build Tool, you should note that `.NET 5.0` is released since `16.8`. So you should update your build tool to `16.8.x` and then you can build `.NET 5.0` projects.

**Also**, if you just use command line, you can directly download [.NET 5.0 Sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and then use `dotnet build`.

And if you installed `.NET 5.0` and want to use VS IDE, you should also update VS to `16.8.x`.

Comment: Updated, thank you! But i have to relay on msbuild.exe to make use of the WiX Toolset